# How to prevent windows from asking you what to do with this file?

Tags: windows, windows-10, file-transfer

So I have a Windows 10 computer and I tried to transfer 100 GB of data, approx. 10000 files and 10 hours of transfer time. I want to run this copying process overnight but the problem is, on file 3000, windows pauses and says:

> There are mutiple instances with the same name: **desktop.ini**. Do you want to keep the files or discard one of them, or skip?

This pops up and it ruins my whole file transfering process because windows won't continue, I also can't find all the hidden "desktop.ini" files in my 10000 file folder. Is there some registry associated with this so that windows automatiacally skips all files with the same name, so I dont have to worry about it pausing overnight?

Comment: For large file operations I would recommend not to use Windows Explorer. Use command-line tool `robocopy.exe` instead (included in Windows10).

Comment: @Robert Will robocopy.exe transfer files faster than generic explorer transfer?

Comment: @VJZGamingHD yes most likely, the GUI (Explorer) is considerably slower than RoboCopy or PowerShell in the majority of cases... Also when using robocopy use the /XF flag to exclude the desktop.ini file.

Comment: I am not sure if it is really faster but more reliable. And additionally it has the mirror `/MIR` mode which allows to abort and restart the copy operation and copy only the remaining missing files. Robocopy by default retries a copy operation multiple times if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do the transfer and Robocopy will be the fastest way.

I have used this free program called FreeFileSync many times and it can exclude files or folders that are not needed like Robocopy can. The advantage with Freefilesync is ease of use for people that prefer a graphical user interface (GUI).

[FreeFileSync](https://freefilesync.org/)

The settings menu allows you to add and remove files/folders to exclude from the transfer as seen in the image below.

[image]